# Sort Configurable Attribute Options Alphabetically Except for First One (Default)

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, dropdown-attribute

I've made changes to my Magento code to remove the "Choose an Option" in the drop down for configurable products.  Now, I want to ensure that the drop down menu options are loaded in alphabetical order except for the first option.  I want the current first value to remain the same.  The first associated sku should be the default, pre-selected options on the page.

**app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php**

```
protected function _loadPrices()
{
    if ($this->count()) {
        $pricings = array(
            0 => array()
        );

        if ($this->getHelper()->isPriceGlobal()) {
            $websiteId = 0;
        } else {
            $websiteId = (int)Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
            $pricing[$websiteId] = array();
        }

        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(array('price' => $this->_priceTable))
            ->where('price.product_super_attribute_id IN (?)', array_keys($this->_items));

        if ($websiteId > 0) {
            $select->where('price.website_id IN(?)', array(0, $websiteId));
        } else {
            $select->where('price.website_id = ?', 0);
        }

        $query = $this->getConnection()->query($select);

        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            $pricings[(int)$row['website_id']][] = $row;
        }

        $values = array();

        foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
            $productAttribute = $item->getProductAttribute();
            if (!($productAttribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)) {
                continue;
            }
            $options = $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();

            $optionsByValue = array();
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $optionsByValue[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }

            $assProds = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                         ->getUsedProducts(array($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()), $this->getProduct());

            foreach ($assProds
                     as $associatedProduct) {

                $optionValue = $associatedProduct->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

                if (array_key_exists($optionValue, $optionsByValue)) {
                    // If option available in associated product
                    if (!isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue])) {
                        // If option not added, we will add it.
                        $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue] = array(
                            'product_super_attribute_id' => $item->getId(),
                            'value_index'                => $optionValue,
                            'label'                      => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
                            'default_label'              => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
                            'store_label'                => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
                            'is_percent'                 => 0,
                            'pricing_value'              => null,
                            'use_default_value'          => true
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($pricings[0] as $pricing) {
            // Addding pricing to options
            $valueKey = $pricing['product_super_attribute_id'] . ':' . $pricing['value_index'];
            if (isset($values[$valueKey])) {
                $values[$valueKey]['pricing_value']     = $pricing['pricing_value'];
                $values[$valueKey]['is_percent']        = $pricing['is_percent'];
                $values[$valueKey]['value_id']          = $pricing['value_id'];
                $values[$valueKey]['use_default_value'] = true;
            }
        }

        if ($websiteId && isset($pricings[$websiteId])) {
            foreach ($pricings[$websiteId] as $pricing) {
                $valueKey = $pricing['product_super_attribute_id'] . ':' . $pricing['value_index'];
                if (isset($values[$valueKey])) {
                    $values[$valueKey]['pricing_value']     = $pricing['pricing_value'];
                    $values[$valueKey]['is_percent']        = $pricing['is_percent'];
                    $values[$valueKey]['value_id']          = $pricing['value_id'];
                    $values[$valueKey]['use_default_value'] = false;
                }
            }
        }

/*          foreach ($values as $key => $row) {
            $val[$key]  = $row['label'];
            $i++;
        }
        array_multisort($val, SORT_ASC, $values);
*/

        $val = array_column($values, 'label');
        $val[0] = ""; // fix first row
        array_multisort($val, SORT_ASC, $values);

        foreach ($values as $data) {
            $this->getItemById($data['product_super_attribute_id'])->addPrice($data);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

At the bottom, I added code to sort (`array_multisort`) the $values multidimensional array by 'label'.  I also added code to ignore the first row when sorting.  This works for the first attribute but the 2nd and 3rd attributes are in alphabetical order (default not pre-selected).  Is this the approach I should use?  Am I missing something?  Any suggestions?  I'm using Magento 1.9.1.

Current Results:

```
Color
    Blue
    Black
    Green
    Orange
    Red
    Yellow
Size
    Large
    Small
```

Blue and Small should be the defaults but attribute 2 is not showing correct default:

```
Color
    Blue
    Black
    Green
    Orange
    Red
    Yellow
Size
    Small
    Large
```